# boost::thread and destructor of contained classes

Tags: multithreading, boost, memory-leaks, destructor

I would like to understand the behaviour of this code.

```
class Foo
{
      public:
            Foo();
            ~Foo();
            void run();
            int* get();
    private:
            int *a;
};

Foo::Foo()
{
     a=NULL;       
}
void Foo::run()
{
       if ( a==NULL)
            a = new int[30000];
}

int* Foo::get()
{
    return a;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    cout << "destructor called" << endl;
    if ( a!=NULL)
            delete a;
}

int main()
{
        Foo *a = new Foo();

        boost::thread Foothread( &Foo::run, a);
        // Some very long computation that sometimes access 

        int *b  = a->get();
        cout << *b << endl; 
        //Foothread.join();
        //delete a;
        //Foothread.join();

        return 0;
}
```

This code causes a memory leak of 120000 bytes because variable a is not destructed, so when I explicitly delete it the leak disappers and everything should be ok.

Now if I instead of dynamically allocate a, I use static allocation the destructor is called many times!!!

```
int main()
{
        Foo a;

        boost::thread Foothread( &Foo::run, a);
        // Some very long computation that sometimes access "a"
        Foothread.join();
        int *b  = a.get();
        cout << *b << endl; 

        return 0;
}
```

and the ouput is 
    destructor called, a was 0
    Now a is 0
    destructor called, a was 0
    Now a is 0
    destructor called, a was 0
    Now a is 0
    destructor called, a was 0
    Now a is 0
    destructor called, a was 0
    Now a is 0
    destructor called, a was 0
    Now a is 0
    destructor called, a was 0x75e300
    Now a is 0
    Segmentation fault

The destructor is called N times!!

Now I would like to know how to safe allocate and deallocate both class member variable and objects using boost::thread and why the thread destructor doesn't handle the class destructor explicitly.

Could someone give me an hint? Should boost::smart_ptr help me? I have to allocate memory with malloc (because I need to use some old C API), how can I do it thread-safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions create an object of class Foo in Thread 1 and call its `run` method from a background thread (Thread 2). This background thread terminates, when `run` returns.

`run` actually initializes the object of class `Foo`. One problem in your code is, that you may do *some very long computation that sometimes access "a"* in Thread 1 **before** Thread 2 finished the intialization of `a`. This causes a race condition. To avoid it, you should call `Foothread.join()` before you access the `Foo::a` in `a`.

Some other points:

- in Foo::~Foo() you do not need to check if the pointer about to delete differs from `NULL`
- an array `a` created with `new` must be deleted with `delete[] a;`

Comment: So, if I want to periodically access data contained in "a" should I first join the thread, access a and the detach the thread again?
How does this influence the performance of the program? (I would be able the access data contained inside a glut program in the update function)

Comment: If you do a `join`, your thread waits for the joined thread to terminate. The point is: In your example there is no multithreading after `Foo::run` has finished (`Foothread` is no longer running). And it is not safe to access `Foo::a` until the initialization has finished. Actually there is no need to do multithreading at all unless your main thread has some work to be done, which does **not** need an initialized `Foo` object.

Comment: ok, but let's suppose the method run here should not end until a key is pressed, in that case how the memory is freed and the thread is destructed? In which order?

Comment: It depends... If you call `thread::join` from main, the initial thread waits for the other thread to terminate. So the order is: 1st: Thread termination, 2nd: destruction of foo due to exit of main.

If you do not join and do not press a key `main` will exit at a certain point in time. Thus, the instance of `Foo` will be deleted. But the thread keeps running for a small while. **After** the exit of main the runtime stops all other threads.

Comment: so do you think can be a good option to give some seconds to destroy the thread before exiting? this can avoid the thread to be stopped suddenly and give it time to stop all the internal processes (Streams, communications with hardware etc? )

Answer (score 1):

Should it be &a in the second case?

```
boost::thread Foothread( &Foo::run, &a);
```

Comment: yes, but the compiler allows me also to use boost::thread Foothread( &Foo::run, a); O_O very strange